# cURL development load slowly after uploaded in server PHP

Tags: php, curl

Hi **"I would like to ask an assistance"** yes, you read it right, I don't know what's happening to my cURL development program. Straight to the point, I have cURL development program which works perfect and faster in my localhost xampp, I even receives a response correctly. But I thought i'm done on my work, until I uploaded it to my cpanel, It became superslow in terms loading, It cannot receives any response anymore also after loading.

I just receive 
`Curl Error: 7`

OR

`Curl Error: 28`

I don't know whats this weird thing. I googled already the errors (`cURL error(7)` "It says connection issue to host, but its impossible, I can connect to host in my localhost." `cURL error: 28` I have made some adjustment also to my curl_opt() you see in my comment below.

Here's my code

```
$headers = array(
                // "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                "SOAPAction: \"http://domain.org/\"",
                "Host: domain.com",
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                ); 

$url = $soapUrl;

// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$soap_do = curl_init() or die('Error');
set_time_limit(0);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        400);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    true); // try, to solve an issue
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,      10);   // try, to solve an issue
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // try, to solve an issue
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,     400);  // try, to solve an issue
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,        TRUE); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);
```

But still the same, No response coming and loads slow

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into problems with cURL, I place the curl handle that has just completed to PHP's [curl_getinfo](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) function.

Try adding this code just after you run `curl_exec($soap_do);`

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(curl_getinfo($soap_do)); echo '</pre>';
```

curl_getinfo returns an array of data, which is displayed by print_r, and formatted in an easy to read list by the `<pre>` tag.